# What are the best User Interface colors?

Tags: user-interface, colors

Colors like red and green are not visible to people with colour blindness.So is it a good idea to use red or variations of red as a user interface colour?

Comment: *"Best"* is impossible to say. Even just considering accessibility, here are different kinds of colour blindness, not just red-green, and other vision impairments.

Comment: Belongs on [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).  Avoid asking "opinion" questions like this though.